# jquery numeric input converted to 0 when should be null

Tags: jquery, input

I have a table in which I am using inline editing.    In the example below this column comes back as data type int from the SQL query that populates the table.   When the table is first displayed the column has a null value.   when the user edits the row they can set it to a numeric value.

However what I see is that if they do not set a value -  leave the box empty -  then it really does get set to `0` rather than left `null`.    `tr.find('#mycolumn').val()`  must be returning `0` and I really want it to stay `null`.   In this particular data set the value of `0` has meaning and is an acceptable value to use, so I cannot infer back in my data base method that if `0` is passed in I should really treat as `null`......

the jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            /**blah blah balh*//

            $('.saverec').on('click', function () {
                var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
                var studentid = tr.find('#StudentID').html();

                var col2 = tr.find('#i_col2v').val();
                /**blah blah balh*//

              $.post('p_AV_FP',
                     { StudentId: studentid, TeacherId: teacherid, Assesment_Key: assesment_key, Trial_key: trial_key, Col1: col1, Col2: col2, Col3: col3, Col4: col4, Col5: col5, Col6: col6, Col7: col7, Col8: col8, Col9: col9, Col1k: col1k, Col2k: col2k, Col3k: col3k, Col4k: col4k, Col5k: col5k, Col6k: col6k, Col7k: col7k, Col8k: col8k, Col9k: col9k },
                     function (rec) {

                         /* PARSE out HTML */
                         var html4 = String(rec).substring(0, String(rec).indexOf("\n"));
                         var json1 = "'" + html4 + "'";
                         var myrec = $.parseJSON(html4);

                         /* POSTBACK VALUES */

                         tr.find('#col2v').text(myrec.Col2v);
```

and down in my table the row I am using as my example:

```
    mygrid.Column("Col2",
                header : "Accuracy",
                format: @<text>
                            <span id="col2v" class="displaymode">@item.Col2v</span>
                            <input id="i_col2v" class="editmode" value="@item.Col2v" style="width:30px;" />
                        </text>),
```

I want to know how to make sure that only entered values are passed to my post method, rather than have it interpret an empty string as `""` or an empty numeric box as `0` -  I really do want them to be `null`.

how would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the data type on @item.Col2v? Is it nullable?

Comment: in my sql database it is an int.   yes it can be null